# How to send multiple posts requests in a rest API by Id, node.js?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, post

I have the following post method in a REST API I've created using node.js below. Currently, this post method works for one Id. That is, I can specify one Id for which I want to send the post request. I want to update this post request so that I can input a list of Ids. Namely, given a list of Ids, I would iterate through the Ids and send a post request with the same message body, per Id. In that case, I'd be sending multiple post requests, each could potentially succeed or fail. At the end of all the posts, I'd like to return a message like "Ids: ______ succeeded and Ids: _____ failed". Given the structure of my post request, any ideas on how I might be able to do this effectively?

```
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    if (isNil(req['api_key'])) {
        next();
    } else {
        try{
            if (isNil(req.body) || isEmpty(req.body)) {
                logInfo({message: 'Request body is empty or null.', data: req.body}, 'API');
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: 'Request body is empty or null.',
                });
            }
            let payload = {
                topic: process.env.KAFKA_TOPIC,
                messages: [], 
                key: null, 
                timestamp: 
            };

            payload.key = isNil(req.body.Id) ? '': req.body.Id;
            payload.messages = JSON.stringify(req.body);
            let result = await kafkaService.publish(new Array(payload));
            logInfo({message: 'Settings API Result.', data: result, source: scriptName}, 'API')

        } catch(err){
            let err_more = { message: 'Error Caught in POST', data: req.body, source: scriptName};
            logError(err, err_more, 'API');
            newRelic.noticeError(err, err_more);
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Server Error. Can\'t process your request.',
                payload: req.body
            });
        }

        return res.send({
            message: 'Settings sent for processing.',
            payload: req.body
        });
    }
}, async (req, res, next) => {
    logInfo({message: 'Unauthorized access to settings API', data: req.body}, 'API');
    return res.status(401).send({
        message: 'Unauthorized access to settings API.'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a *makeRequest* function, then posting the body as shown below with an id array and a message.

We'd loop over each id and publish each message:

```
async function makeRequest(id, messages) {
    try { 
        let payload = {
            topic: process.env.KAFKA_TOPIC,
            messages: [], 
            key: null, 
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString()
        };

        payload.key = isNil(id) ? '': id;
        payload.messages = messages;
       
        let result = await kafkaService.publish(new Array(payload));
        logInfo({ id, message: 'Settings API Result.', data: result, source: scriptName}, 'API')
        return { id, success: true, result };
    } catch(err) {
        logError({id, message: 'Settings API Result.', data: err }, 'API')
        return { id, success: false, result: null, err };
    };
}

router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    req['api_key'] = "Dd";
    if (isNil(req['api_key'])) {
        next();
    } else {
        try{
            if (isNil(req.body) || isEmpty(req.body)) {
                logInfo({message: 'Request body is empty or null.', data: req.body}, 'API');
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: 'Request body is empty or null.',
                });
            }
            if (!Array.isArray(req.body.id)) {
                logInfo({message: 'ID list required.', data: req.body}, 'API');
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: 'ID list required.',
                });
            }
            if (!(req.body.message)) {
                logInfo({message: 'Message required.', data: req.body}, 'API');
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: 'Message required.',
                });
            }
            let results = [];
            for(let id of req.body.id) {
                results.push(await makeRequest(id, JSON.stringify(req.body.message)));
            }
            const msg = `Ids: ${results.filter(r => r.success).map(r => r.id).join(",")} succeeded and Ids: ${results.filter(r => !r.success).map(r => r.id).join(",")} failed`;
            logInfo(msg, 'API');
            return res.send({
                message: 'Settings sent for processing: ' + msg,
                payload: req.body
            });
        } catch(err){
            let err_more = { message: 'Error Caught in POST', data: req.body, source: scriptName};
            logError(err, err_more, 'API');
            newRelic.noticeError(err, err_more);
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Server Error. Can\'t process your request.',
                payload: req.body
            });
        }
    }
}, async (req, res, next) => {
    logInfo({message: 'Unauthorized access to settings API', data: req.body}, 'API');
    return res.status(401).send({
        message: 'Unauthorized access to settings API.'
    });
});
```

The POST body would look like so:

```
{
    "id": [ 1, 2, 3],
    "message": "testMessage"
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Terry Lennox!! This makes a lot of sense. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: No problem at all! Glad to help and anytime I answer a question, I learn something new!

Comment: Suppose instead my post body looked like: {"id": [1,2,3], "message": "testMessage"}. Would I be able to iterate through the `req.body.id`? Currently I'm getting an error if I try to iterate through the ids in that sort of way. Might you know how I could do such an iteration?

Comment: Absolutely,  I'll update the answer in a little while!

Comment: No problem at all!

Comment: I've added to the code where I'm now checking if Ids are an array. If they are an array I do the post as required, if not I send status 400 and say it must be an array. I've added a chai http unit test for this but am having some trouble accepting the ids as an array. Might you have any insights on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65239249/how-to-send-array-in-json-object-for-chaihttp-unit-testing